# How to get JSON from cURL as array in a batch file

Tags: json, windows, bash, batch-file

Hi I'm very new in batch files. I try to do something simular to my bash script. So here is my problem:

I want to get all versions/tags from a github repository to generate a configuration file for the php documentor sami. But how can I write the JSON into a variable in batch to get the versions? In my bash script I did this and it's working fine:

```
function jsonDecode() {
    json=$1
    key=$2

    echo ${json} | jq -r ${key}
}

ghUser="MisterMarlu"
ghRepo="sentence"
json=$(curl "https://api.github.com/repos/${ghUser}/${ghRepo}/tags")
versions=$(echo "${json}" | jq -c ".[]")

for version in ${versions[@]}; do
    versionNumber=$(jsonDecode ${version} ".name")
    echo "    ->add( '${versionNumber}', '${versionNumber}' )" >> ${config}
done

# Here comes alot of code below this for loop..
```

This will output "v0.0.1" and "v0.0.2". Bus how can I do this in a batch file?

**EDIT**
Here is the JSON response where I need just the `"name"` as array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "v0.0.2",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/zipball/v0.0.2",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/tarball/v0.0.2",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "82c4b6d74cc16816104934114766f0328e77ee66",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/commits/82c4b6d74cc16816104934114766f0328e77ee66"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmMTMzMDM1MDMxOnYwLjAuMg=="
  },
  {
    "name": "v0.0.1",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/zipball/v0.0.1",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/tarball/v0.0.1",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "0cf1a83a51716da3f42915c9eab571166845bb0b",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/commits/0cf1a83a51716da3f42915c9eab571166845bb0b"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmMTMzMDM1MDMxOnYwLjAuMQ=="
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To process the output of another program you need a `for /f`
- parsing the lines filtered by `findstr`

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\12\SU_50811698.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "ghUser=MisterMarlu"
Set "ghRepo=sentence"
Set "Version="
For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:, " %%U in ('
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/%ghUser%/%ghRepo%/tags" 2^>Nul ^| findstr /i "\"name\""
') do Set "Version=!Version!,%%~V"
If defined Version (set "Version=%Version:~1%") Else (Set "Version=n/a")
Set Version
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\06\12\SU_50811698.cmd
Version=v0.0.2,v0.0.1
```

You are aware that batch has no real arrays?

Just an alternative in PowerShell:

```
$ghUser="MisterMarlu"
$ghRepo="sentence"
$URL = "https://api.github.com/repos/$ghUser/$ghRepo/tags"
$Json=(curl.exe $URL)|ConvertFrom-json
$Json | Select name
```

---

```
name
----
v0.0.2
v0.0.1
```

Comment: Like I said I'm really new with it and no I didn't know that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

With [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) it's simple as:

```
xidel -s "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/tags" -e "join($json()/name,',')"
```

This puts out: `v0.0.2,v0.0.1`.

To export this as `$config`/`%config%`...
**Bash:**

```
eval "$(xidel -s "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/tags" -e '
  config:=join(
    $json()/name,
    ","
  )' --output-format=bash
)"
```

**Batch:**

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('xidel.exe -s "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/tags" -e ^"
  config:^=join^(
    $json^(^)/name^,
    '^,'
  ^)^" --output-format^=cmd
') DO %%A
```

or...

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('xidel.exe -s "https://api.github.com/repos/MisterMarlu/sentence/tags" -e "config:=join($json()/name,',')" --output-format=cmd') DO %%A
```